# Wikimapia raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wikimapia

How to connect Wikimapia raster layer in QGIS? Is there XYZ tiles URL?
AlpenQuest on Android or very old SAS.Planet always supported Wikimapia layer.
In SAS there is two files and its works:

GetUrlScript.txt

```
begin 
 insert(inttostr((GetX mod 4)+(GetY mod 4)*4),GetURLBase,9);
 ResultURL:=GetURLBase+'x='+inttostr(GetX)+'&y='+inttostr(GetY)+'&zoom='+inttostr(GetZ-1)+'&r=764397&type=hybrid&lng=1';
end.
```

params.txt

```
[PARAMS]
pnum=41
GUID={B30B8F92-5680-410B-962D-E2C650B9CE45}
asLayer=1
name_ru=Wikimapia - растровая
name=Wikimapia - raster
name_uk=WikiMapia - растровий
ParentSubMenu_ru=Подписи и границы
ParentSubMenu=Labels and borders
ParentSubMenu_uk=Підписи та межі
NameInCache=WikiMapHyb
DefURLBase=http://i.wikimapia.org/?
ContentType=image/png,text/plain
Ext=.png
projection=1
sradiusa=6378137
sradiusb=6356752
MimeTypeSubst = "text/plain=image/png"
DetectContentType=1
```

Comment: API (http://wikimapia.org/api) doesn't look like it supports any standard interface such as WMS or WMTS